# accordion only show one item at same time in vue js

Tags: vue.js

//this code in vue js for accordion this is working but not show open only //one at the same time.

//there component and pass props data.

```
<packing-material-category v-for="(category, index) in packingMaterialCategories" :category="category" :key="index"></packing-material-category>
```

//there template to render data.

```
<template>
<div class="packing-categories">
    <div :class="packingCategoryClass">
        <h3 class="packing-category__title" @click="toggleAccordion(category.title)" v-text="category.title" />
        <div v-show="accordionOpen===true" class="packing-category__content">
            <div v-if="category.description" class="packing-category__description" v-text="category.description" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//call method for open and close

```
toggleAccordion() {
```

this.accordionOpen = !this.accordionOpen;
}

Comment: Try to find out what is in `packingMaterialCategories`. It is possible there is only one entry.

Comment: hello sitethief: packingMaterialCategories is object and has a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track which item is shown outside of `packing-material-category` component (value of `openedIndex`) and to pass that value down to components. When value changes in the `packing-material-category` component, you emit event `change-accordion`, and in your parent component you update value of `openedIndex`

Try this

In your parent component, add `openedIndex: 0` to `data`.
If you want everything closed by default, set value to `false`.

Update template to pass down the props `index` and `openedIndex`, so that components know when to show/hide.

```
<packing-material-category
  v-for="(category, index) in packingMaterialCategories"
  :key="index"
  :index="index"
  :openedIndex="openedIndex"
  :category="category"
  @change-accordion="(newOpen) => openedIndex = newOpen"
>
</packing-material-category>
```

And the `packing-material-category` component could look like this

```
<template>
    <div class="packing-categories">
        <div :class="packingCategoryClass">
            <h3 class="packing-category__title" @click="toggleAccordion" v-text="category.title" />
            <div v-show="index === openedIndex" class="packing-category__content">
                <div v-if="category.description" class="packing-category__description" v-text="category.description" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: [
      'category',
      'index',       // index of this component
      'openedIndex', // which item should be shown/opened
    ],
    data() {
      return {
        packingCategoryClass: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      toggleAccordion() {
        // Show current item. If already opened, hide current item
        let value = this.index === this.openedIndex ? false : this.index;
        // notify parent component about the change
        this.$emit('change-accordion', value)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: :openedIndex="openedIndex"  this not undefined how can use this.

Comment: `openedIndex` should be in your parents `data`. You are passing that value down to the child component `:openedIndex="openedIndex"`. And when the value changes, you are `$emit` (emitting event) from child component so your parent component knows that it needs to update the value of `openedIndex`

Comment: You can find more about this in the documentation: [Passing Data to Child Components with Props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and [Sending Messages to Parents with Events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Sending-Messages-to-Parents-with-Events). Documentation covers this nicely, I recommend you to read it one more time to cover the basics.